# One or more integrations have been reset because of a change to their xml configs - Magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2.4.2, integration, error-message

I'm getting this error in my Magento 2 admin.
"One or more integrations have been reset because of a change to their xml configs."

Looking online i can see about people saying to disable the module "Shopial_Facebook" but checking my system I can see this module does not exist.

[image: Module Check Command]

Does anyone know how i can remove this, I'm using Magento version 2.4.2